# GeoPandas 0.6.1 installed instead of 0.7.0 in conda windows 10

Tags: python, geopandas, windows-10

I have problems using the .clip utility from the GeoPandas package. I found in this post that the problem might be due to the GeoPandas version, since this utility is only available in > 0.7 version.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505660/geopandas-has-no-attribute-clip
```

I tried `conda install geopandas`, but always I receave the notification that the version 0.6.1 will be installed, and not the version 0.7. Is there a way to do it through `conda` and not `pip`?

Comment: Install geopandas from `conda-forge` channel. `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`.

Comment: Same problem. Created env in Anaconda Navigator, installed Spyder 4, conda installed Geopandas but said there were a lot of package conflicts. I'm stuck with 0.6.1. It seems like Geopandas 0.7.0 isn't compatible with any version of Spyder, at least in my situation.

Comment: But @martinfleis' comment worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.

Using the code below was the only way I was able to install Geopandas 0.7.0 using Python 3.7.7:

```
git clone https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git

cd geopandas

pip install .
```

Comment: This does not install 0.7.0 but the latest development version.

Answer (score 4):

GeoPandas development team does not have control over the version which comes from `conda defaults` channel, but it does have control over `conda-forge` channel. GeoPandas installed from `conda-forge` will be always the most recent release, unless there are some other dependency constraints.

If using conda, ideally install GeoPandas using `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas` instead of simple `conda install geopandas`.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem using Anaconda Navigator.

1. I've created one new environment
2. i've install geopandas in conda's environment created at point 1 (the version was 0.6.1)
3. In Anaconda Navigator in the environment I've select geopandas and upgrate to version 0.8.1 (the version available at the time of writing).